# Configuring Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Comparing to working version of my Spring application I've only added  Spring Security plugin to `gradle.build`
`compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')`
 and used `org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt` within one of my classes. Now I'm getting "*Full authentication is required to access this resource*". How to fix this problem or how to exclude all Spring Security features except BCrypt (second is more preferable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring boot, adding this dependency normally enables the OAuth 2 security configuration and its common to get the *Full authentication* error. You can just add the Crypto dependency instead and try.

Maven:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:4.0.1.RELEASE')
```